# Shell Script: Create folder by current date and move .png files inside of that subfolder

Tags: bash, shell

I have tried with following code

```
CUR_DATE=`date +%F`
mkdir "$CUR_DATE"
cd "$CUR_DATE"
mkdir '00UTC'
cd  ~/home/scripts/
for f in $(find . -type f -name "*.png")
do
    mv $f "~/home/scripts/${CUR_DATE}/00UTC"
done
```

Here , all ***.png** files does not move into sub folder 00UTC (which is inside of current date folder).
Any suggestions is helpful.

Comment: You have created a sub directory with a literal name 00UTC and so why are trying to expand it as a variable when using ${00UTC}?

Comment: Quotes prevent `bash` from expanding `~/`.

Comment: Kindly, provide any solution in details.

Comment: `all *.png files does not move into` Where are these "all *png files"? In what directory they reside? In `~/home/scripts/`?

Comment: Yes. All png files inside ~/home/scripts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes prevent `bash` from expanding `~/`. I suggest to replace

```
mv $f "~/home/scripts/${CUR_DATE}/00UTC"
```

with

```
mv "$f" ~/"home/scripts/${CUR_DATE}/00UTC"
```

or

```
mv "$f" "$HOME/home/scripts/${CUR_DATE}/00UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Cyrus pointed out the problem, There are few more things to consider if this is a serious piece of code:

1. First five lines of your code can be done in 2 like this:

   ```
   CUR_DATE=`date +%F`
   mkdir -p "$CUR_DATE/00UTC"
   ```
2. Also you are moving png file from the same directory, thus no need for using ~/, following will work also:

   ```
   for f in $(find . -type f -name "*.png")
   do
     mv $f "$(pwd)/$CUR_DATE/00UTC"
   done
   ```

   or

   ```
   for f in $(find . -type f -name "*.png")
   do
     mv $f "$CUR_DATE/00UTC"
   done
   ```
3. Also running same code over and again will generate same file errors (although it won't be distraous) of moving files that are already moved.